# Vector Math to Determine Gravity Path

Tags: python, scripting, normals, mathematics, vector

I need to code a function that basically traces the path a sphere would roll when placed on a triangulated terrain. The image below shows the problem, but I haven't got a clue how to work with vectors in order to find a solution.

[image: Gravity Trace Illustration]

Pseudocode-wise, I'm looking for:

```
def gravity_trace(face_ABC, point_D):
    ...
    return X
```

I honestly don't know how difficult it will be to fill in the ... above. I'd appreciate any and all help I can get. My math skills are terribly rusty and I have never worked with vector math before.

Thanks!

Comment: Physics Simulation provided by Blender can be investigated by you.  It is not clear this is a Blender Question.  It might just be mathematics such as Gradient.  There is a difference between giving abstract coordinates for a math test and concrete values for a simulation.  Are your values concrete or abstract?  Will the result be displayed in Blender or not?

Comment: The resulting function will be part of an add-on, as is made relatively obvious by the question's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Project plane normal in z direction onto plane.**

Here is a test script. Adds a randomly (*random 0 to 1 radian rotation on x, y, z*) rotated unit circle ngon at cursor, and places an empty on global edge low point.

- The normal of the plane is its local z axis.
- Global -z axis is considered down.
- Find The vector intersection of the line from tip of normal in -z
  direction to the plane. Used `mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane(...)`
- Result is the "downhill" vector.

  - lowest point on circle edge will be
    centre plus the normalized (unit length) downhill vector.

Test script:

```
import bpy
from random import random
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_line_plane as ipp

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(fill_type='NGON')
ob = bpy.context.object
ob.rotation_euler = Vector(random() for axis in 'xyz')
z = Vector((0, 0, 1))
bpy.context.scene.update()
mw = ob.matrix_world

n = (mw.to_3x3() @ z).normalized()
p = mw.translation
v = ipp(p + n, p + n - z, p, n)
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=p + (v - p).normalized())
```

Comment: That should get me most of the way there! I'm going to have to pluck apart what's going on in your solution, but I think I should be able to take what you've given me as a starting point to finding the location on the triangle edge. Thank you!